# Use one binding as default when multiple bindings are present in Dagger

Tags: java, binding, dagger-2, dagger

I have two bindings for a single BaseClass. For example

```
class Base{
}

class A extends Base{}

class C extends Base{}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("b"
Base provideA(){
  return A;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("b")
Base provideB(){
 return B;
}
```

I dont want to sepcify @Named("b") in all the places which needs Base as dependency, but bidining named "B" should be used by default unless explicitly @Named is specified.

```
    class BaseUSer{
    
     //I dont want to annotate base variable in all places @Named, but by default it should use @Named b
@Inject
     public BaseUser(Base /*should use b*/ b, Base @Named("a") a){
      
     }
```

Comment: Duped against [a previous question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483569/default-implementation-using-dagger-if-named-not-found) (which I recently edited with this question in mind). If this isn't applicable to your case, let me know and I can reopen.

Comment: This is the the case. My case is different. I want dagger to inject default binding if Named is NOT specified. If Named is specified use that

Comment: Reopened as requested, but the case isn't different. `@Poison Apple` and `Apple` are as independent as `Apple` and `Orange`. It's just another binding to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same case as [the dupe I had linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483569/default-implementation-using-dagger-if-named-not-found): `@Named("B") Base` and `Base` are entirely different bindings to Dagger, so there's no "default" to set, just a different injection to bind.

The best you can do is to use `@Binds` or `@Provides` to bind `Base`, which won't conflict with `@Named("B") Base`.

```
// Base injections without a @Named annotation should act as if they're @Named("B").
@Binds abstract Base bindBase(@Named("B") Base bBase);
```